# Snowflake Stored Procedure to execute create statement for external table

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to create a stored procedure in snowflake that takes arguments to generate 'create statement' for external table using metadata of the staged file from *infer schema* and executing it.
Since i am fairly new to Snowflake Stored procedure  , would really appreciate inputs on how to achieve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DatabaseName.SchemaName.TEST_PROCEDURE(DB_NAME STRING, SCHEMA_NAME 
STRING, TABLE_NAME STRING , FILEPATH STRING)
returns string 
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = `
   SELECT
   'CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE ' || DB_NAME ||'.'||SCHEMA_NAME||'.'||TABLE_NAME|| ' (' 
||
LISTAGG(
  CLEAN_COLUMN || ' ' || TYPE || ' AS (' ||
  'VALUE:'|| CLEAN_COLUMN || '::' || TYPE || ')', ', ') AS QUERY_TEXT
 FROM (
SELECT *
,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%#%' THEN '"'||COLUMN_NAME||'"' ELSE COLUMN_NAME END AS CLEAN_COLUMN
from table(
  INFER_SCHEMA(
    LOCATION => '@db.src_xxx.stg_yyyy/2021-awdfg'
    ,FILE_FORMAT => '@db.src_xxx.parquet'
  )
) A
 )
`
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
var result = sql.execute();
    return 'Success';
$$;
```

Comment: I assume it will generate only one CREATE TABLE statement, is it correct?

Comment: Can you share the create statement how you want to create an external table?

Comment: Yes it will generate one CREATE TABLE statement using the metadata of the staged file as specified in location.

Comment: Since there are number of files in the staging , procedure should 'create table' for each one when called ( thus parameterizing the file location)

Answer (score 0):

The create external table supports `USING TEMPLATE` feature:

[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE: Derive Column Definitions from Staged Files — Preview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-08.html#create-external-table-derive-column-definitions-from-staged-files-preview):

> With this release, **Snowflakes supports creating new external tables with the column definitions derived from a set of staged files containing semi-structured data.** Include the USING TEMPLATE keywords in your CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE statement
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE myet
> USING TEMPLATE (
>       SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
>       FROM TABLE(
>       INFER_SCHEMA(
>             LOCATION=>'@filestage',
>             FILE_FORMAT=>'ffparquet'
>            )
>       )
> )
> location=@filestage
> file_format=ffparquet
> auto_refresh=false;
> ```
>
> This feature is currently limited to Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, and ORC files.